# Conversion from Int to String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a login page that Username is the emaloyee ID which is an Integer. however to validate my loging I need to convert it to string, but it continuesly give me same error.

I need help here: `var user = db.EMPLOYEEs.Where(u => u.EMP_ID == model.EMP_ID && u.EMP_PASSWORD == model.EMP_PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();`

I have tried all of these but sill give me same error :

```
string s = i.ToString();
string s = Convert.ToString(i);
string s = string.Empty + i;
string s = new StringBuilder().Append(i).ToString();
```

---

[image]

---

I get another error down on

```
serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID; error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string[]'
```

what I suppose to do with this one?

[image]

here is my code :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = "")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int modelID = int.Parse(model.EMP_ID);
                var user = db.EMPLOYEEs.Where(u => u.EMP_ID == modelID && u.EMP_PASSWORD == model.EMP_PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
                    if ( user !=null)
                {
                    var roles = db.EMPLOYEEs.Select(m => m.RoleROLE_ID).ToArray();

                    CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
                    serializeModel.UserId = user.EMP_ID;
                    serializeModel.FirstName = user.EMP_FIRST_NAME;
                    serializeModel.LastName = user.EMP_LAST_NAME;
                    serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID;
```

Comment: When complaining about an error, it's a good idea to mention what the error is.

Comment: it is on the question now! thanx

Comment: @NilR Can you post the test instead of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screen I would assume you should convert the `u.EMP_ID`, not the `model.EMP_ID`

You can also go with `Int.Parse(model.EMP_ID)`

To keep it readable and efficient I would go with:

```
int modelID = Int.Parse(model.EMP_ID);
var user = db.EMPLOYEEs.Where(u => u.EMP_ID == modelID && u.EMP_PASSWORD == model.EMP_PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
```

First of all, you parse only once. Secondly, you compare `int`s which is a lot faster.

Comment: thank you I get another error down on                     serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID; error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'  what I suppose to do with this one?

Comment: @NilR either: `serializeModel.roles.ToString()` or  `Int.Parse(user.RoleROLE_ID)`. The first option should be faster if you set an additional variable to hold result for that.

Comment: I can't the first one give me errors and don't take them :(

Comment: @NilR edit your question to provide more info on that or create new one. I don't know what happens from such a short description.

Comment: @NilR you try to assign a number to an array. Do you want to add this int to the array or what?

Comment: this did the magic : serializeModel.roles = new string[]{ user.RoleROLE_ID.toString() }

Answer (score 0):

just pull that conversion out of the `Where` clause:

```
string empID = Convert.ToString(model.EMP_ID);
var user = db.EMPLOYEEs
             .Where(u => u.EMP_ID == empID && u.EMP_PASSWORD == model.EMP_PASSWORD)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it didn't have at the first place before error and I changed to this one but still doesn't work...

Comment: i did this : int modelID = Int.Parse(model.EMP_ID);
var user = db.EMPLOYEEs.Where(u => u.EMP_ID  and worked fine; however I have another error that down on serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID; error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' what I suppose to do with this one?